# return value after callback function Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't Know is below a valid question? or Just my stupidity.

```
 function IsSlaExists(department) {
     var flag = "";
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: "Type=ISSLAEXISTS&Department=" + encodeURI(escape(department)),
         url: "class-accessor.php",
         success: function (data) {
             //flag=data;  
             flag = "YES";
         }
     });
     return flag;
 }

 alert(IsSlaExists('department'));
```

i'm trying to return the value of `flag` but function returns blanks even if i set the value of flag maually. 
what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the ajax requests did work right? What will happen, if you add a function for failed request?

Comment: Ajax requests are (almost) always asynchronous, so your `return` statement is happening before the POST request has time to complete.

Comment: Why didn't you try to alert flag inside of callback function?

Comment: @shin it's working in callback function

Comment: What's happening is that the `success` callback is being called when, and only when, the ajax request has finished (and succeeded). You need to understand that you are making an asynchronous request, therefore your `success` callback is being called **after** `return flag;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: "Type=ISSLAEXISTS&Department=" + encodeURI(escape(department)),
       url: "class-accessor.php"
}).done(function(r){
      alert("flag");
});
```

This would give you the alert WHEN the AJAX request was successfull. `r` would contain the data that the response got you. You can now, for example, call another function inside the done function that process the request.

Since $.ajax returns a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), you could return just the ajax call and then chain the functions together

```
function ajaxCall(department) {
    return  $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: "Type=ISSLAEXISTS&Department=" + encodeURI(escape(department)),
           url: "class-accessor.php"
    });
}

ajaxCall("myDept").done(function(response){
   alert(response);
})
```

Comment: please understand my prroblem; i want a function which i could use to return a value. in alternative your solution i can simply use the `ajax success`. i want some way by which i could just return value like `var val= ajaxCall('Dep');`